# Fluent NHibernate - Querying child property collections in batch rather than individually

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have an entity with multiple collections of other entities on it, and I'd like to eager load them, ideally in one batch.  Example setup below:

```
public Entity1
{
    public virtual int Prop1 {get;set;}
    public virtual string Prop2 {get;set;}
    public virtual IList<Entity2> Prop3 {get;set;}
    public virtual IList<Entity3> Prop4 {get;set;}
}

public Entity2
{
    public virtual int Prop1 {get;set;}
    public virtual string Prop2 {get;set;}
}

public Entity3
{
    public virtual int Prop1 {get;set;}
    public virtual string Prop2 {get;set;}
    public virtual IList<Entity1> Prop3 {get;set;}
}
```

Mapping for Entities:

```
public class Entity1Map : ClassMap<Entity1>
{
    public ClientMap()
    {
        Table("Clients");
        Id(m => m.Prop1);
        Map(m => m.Prop2);
    }
}

public class Entity1Map : ClassMap<Entity1>
{
    public Entity1Map()
    {
        Table("Entity1Table");
        Id(m => m.Prop1);
        Map(m => m.Prop2);
        HasMany(m => m.Prop3).KeyColumn("Prop1").LazyLoad().NotFound.Ignore();
        HasMany(m => m.Prop4).KeyColumn("Prop1").LazyLoad().NotFound.Ignore();
    }
}

public class Entity2Map : ClassMap<Entity2>
{
    public Entity2Map()
    {
        Table("Entity2Table");
        Id(m => m.Prop1);
        Map(m => m.Prop2);
    }
}

public class Entity3Map : ClassMap<Entity3>
{
    public Entity3Map()
    {
        Table("Entity3Table");
        Id(m => m.Prop1);
        Map(m => m.Prop2);
        HasOne(m => m.Prop3).ForeignKey("Prop1").LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

And querying the database with:

```
var query = session.CreateCriteria<Entity1>()
                .CreateCriteria("Prop3", "prop3", JoinType.InnerJoin)
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property("Prop2"), "Criteria!"))
                .SetFetchMode("Prop3", FetchMode.Join)
                .SetFetchMode("Prop4", FetchMode.Join);

var clients = query.Future<Entity1>().ToList();

//Do other things here with eager loaded collections
```

When I query the database for entity 1, I get a return of a collection of Entity 1 - as I expect I might, however, using NHProf, I can then see a single query being created for each of entity 2/3 to go to the database and collect them individually, meaning that a 10 row return of entity 1 will fire 3 times that many queries.  Is there a way to batch the eager loading queries, so that instead of each of them doing a

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE id = XXX
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE id = YYY
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE id = ZZZ
```

NHibernate will produce something more like

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE id IN (XXX,YYY,ZZZ)
```

And thus not need to query the database so many times?

Any help much appreciated, let me know if there is more detail required.

Comment: I've managed to "solve" this by adding a batch size onto the properties that were retrieving collections - went onto something else for a while and only returned to this the other day.  The batch size on the property makes NHibernate batch up the queries and does the join using an IN statement as above.  Not 100% sure that this is a real fix or not, but it might help someone in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to make each join in a separate future query. Your query is a mess so is mine:

```
session.CreateCriteria<Entity1>()
    .CreateCriteria("Prop3", "prop3", JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property("Prop2"), "Criteria!"))
    .Future<Entity1>();

session.CreateCriteria<Entity1>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property("Prop2"), "Criteria!"))
    .SetFetchMode("Prop2", FetchMode.Join)
    .Future<Entity1>();

var query = session.CreateCriteria<Entity1>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property("Prop2"), "Criteria!"))
    .SetFetchMode("Prop4", FetchMode.Join)
    .Future<Entity1>();

var clients = query.ToList();
```

Comment: The query itself doesn't seem to be the problem as the criteria produced were correct, it just happened that it was creating too many of the correct queries.

Comment: Did you try to break each relation in a separate future query?

Comment: I've not tried splitting them down no, I'm not sure whether I can split them down properly, as the criteria in question only apply to one of the three relations - the others are just there for data retrieval.  I'll give it a try when I get a chance and update.

Comment: Then you should specify the criteria in only 1 place. Try it. It works. I am doing this for so long. Just do this without any criteria at first and experiment.